# Are nested matches a bad practice in idiomatic Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a `get_url_content` function and don't care about errors (it's just a test). It returns an `Option<String>`.

```
extern crate hyper;

use std::io::Read;
use hyper::client::Client;

fn get_url_content(url: &str) -> Option<String> {
    let client = Client::new();
    let mut s = String::new();

    match client.get(url).send() {
        Ok(mut res) => {
            match res.read_to_string(&mut s) {
                Ok(_) => {
                    Some(s)
                },
                Err(_) => {
                    None
                }
            }
        },
        Err(_) => {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

This function works fine but I find it's not easy to read. I think there are some best practices about this kind of case to make it more readable. Are nested matches a bad practice (like callback hell in JS) and if so, how to avoid it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The easiest way to make things a bit cleaner is to drop some braces:

```
match client.get(url).send() {
    Ok(mut res) =>
        match res.read_to_string(&mut s) {
            Ok(_) => Some(s),
            Err(_) => None,
        },
    Err(_) => None,
}
```

The inner match can be expressed a little cleaner perhaps as

```
match client.get(url).send() {
    Ok(mut res) =>
        res.read_to_string(&mut s).ok().map(|_| s),

    Err(_) => None,
}
```

This suggests using a `map` on the outer type (to get `Result<Option<_>, _>`) and then dropping the result with `.unwrap_or(None)` or `.unwrap_or_default()`

```
client.get(url).send()
      .map(|mut res| res.read_to_string(&mut s).ok().map(|_| s))
      .unwrap_or(None)
```

Comment: Doesn't the `.map(|mut res| res.read_to_string(&mut s).ok().map(|_| s))` fail because `s` is borrowed mutably and returned in the same expression?

Comment: It works. Thx for this step by step answer, it helps me to understand better Rust.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson No, since the output's lifetime doesn't depend on the borrow.

Comment: @rap-2-h I should probably mention that my favourite is the second version - the last one just replaces two `match` branches with two function calls.

Answer (score 18):

`Result` and `Option` have some great methods for making code like that simpler.

```
fn get_url_content(url: &str) -> Option<String> {
    let client = Client::new();

    let res = client.get(url)
                    .send()
                    .ok()  // Convert to Option, discarding error
                    .and_then(|mut res| {
                        let mut s = String::new();
                        let result = res.read_to_string(&mut s);
                        result.ok().map(|_| s)
                     }
           })
}
```

I recommend looking through the documentation for [Result](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) and [Option](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html); there are methods for most combinations of conversions between them, and acting on either the success or error half.

If you can change `get_url_content` to return a `Result`, I would recommend that (see [the error handling documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html).  With your own error type and some implementations of `From`, the function then becomes (

```
fn get_url_content(url: &str) -> Result<String, MyError> {
    let client = Client::new();
    let mut s = String::new();

    let got = try!(client.get(url));
    let sent = try!(got.send());
    try!(sent.read_to_string(s));
    Ok(s)
}
```

And probably even simpler with the new `?` operator.